# regexp parse multiple key pair values with delimiter that might be part of the value pair

Tags: regex, capture-group

I am having troubles to **get groups for each key-pair value** from a string.
The input string is something like:

`sample1= "key1.1=val1,key2=2,key3=3,key4=last"`

expected 4 groups:
`key1.1=val1` `key2=2` `key3=3` `key4=last`

**but also possible**

`sample2= "key1.1=val11,key2.1=2,1,key33=3,key44=last"`

*note that here in `sample2`, the `key2.1` has the value `2,1`*

expected 4 groups: `key1.1=val11` `key2.1=2,1` `key33=3` `key44=last`

I am unable to get all the groups and specially to deal with the case where the delimiter `,` between the pairs can also be part of the value of one key.

I am trying something like:
`(?:^|,)([^=,]+)=([^=,]+)(?:,|$)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on commas that are followed by one or more characters other than commas, followed by an equal sign. That is, split on matches of the regular expression

```
,(?=[^,]+=)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/voknUe/1)

---

The method or function you use to split the string on matches of this expression depends on the language you are using, which you have not specified. In Ruby, for example, you would write

```
"key1.1=val11,key2.1=2,1,key33=3,key44=last".split(/,(?=[^,]+=)/)
  #=> ["key1.1=val11", "key2.1=2,1", "key33=3", "key44=last"]
```

---

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
,        # match a comma
(?=      # begin a positive lookahead
  [^,]+  # match one or more characters other than commas
  =      # match an equal sign
)        # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: Alg_D, most languages have a split method or function breaks a string up into pieces between matches of a string (such as a comma, ",") or a regular expression. The pieces are then placed into an array or list. Sometimes you can create the desired array of pieces of the strings by either matching a regular expression or by splitting.